# No Guarda SparceBooleanArray Listview Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy queriendo guardar las positions de los items marcados en listView mediante un chekbox en cada items. Cada vez que hago el check en los items sólo me guarda el ultimo dato checkeado. Para comprobar le hice que muestre con cada check un Log de sparseBooleanArray.size() en la consola. El resultado que me da es siempre 1. Sea False o True. Cómo guardar todos los items marcados?

```
 public View getView(final int i, View view1, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final GuardarCheckBoxPosition guardarCheck = new GuardarCheckBoxPosition(this);


    Chekcompra.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            GuardarPositionListview(i,b);



    return view1;
}
public void GuardarPositionListview(int position, boolean b){
    SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray(0);
    sparseBooleanArray.put(position,b); //aqui tendria que guardar a mi parecer

    Log.i("BooleanArrayPosition:"," "+sparseBooleanArray.size());


}
```

El resultado del Log al marcar tres casillas seguidas es:

```
12-21 22:05:00.313 3683-3683/? I/BooleanArrayPosition::  1
12-21 22:05:10.298 3683-3683/? I/BooleanArrayPosition::  1
12-21 22:05:11.732 3683-3683/? I/BooleanArrayPosition::  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas inicializando la instancia del `SparseBooleanArray` siempre que se ejecuta el metodo `GuardarPosicionListView`. Intenta declararla como campo en la clase para que todos los elementos que agregues, se agreguen a una misma instancia:

```
// iniciamos una instancia por de la clase
private SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray(0);

public void GuardarPositionListview(int position, boolean b){

    // le agregamos el elemento por cada vez ue se ejecuta el metodo
    sparseBooleanArray.put(position,b); 

    Log.i("BooleanArrayPosition:"," "+sparseBooleanArray.size()); // aqui incrementara siempre que se ejecuta el metodo
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Disculpe la tandanza. Ahora probé tu recomendación y me funcionó. Eso era el problema.. Graciassss,.. por fin podré avanzar :D